# Static function in a Class gives the error: two or more data types in declaration of

Tags: c++, class, sorting, compare

I try to use a custom compare function and use it in sort and heap. Right now the class node uses  operatir<. I defined Cmpr as non-static and got the non_static function member error.I tried to make it static:

```
class Node{
public:
    int id;
    int dist;
    Node(int node_id, int fdist = -1):
        id (node_id),
        dist (fdist)
        {};
    bool operator<(const Node & other) const{
        return dist > other.dist;
    }

    static bool Cmpr(Node a, Node b){
        return a->dist > b->dist;
    }   
};
```

I always get the following error:

```
file.cpp on line 14:36: error: two or more data types in declaration of 'Cmpr'
 static bool Cmpr(Node a, Node b){
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: s/`static bool Cmpr(Node a, Node b){`/`static bool Cmpr(Node* a, Node* b){`

Comment: Ah, the Grateful sed. More a fan of Halley and his Comet's classic awk around the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the exact code you tested with, but I see another error, the compiler will complain about. In:

```
static bool Cmpr(Node a, Node b){
    return a->dist > b->dist;
}
```

You treat Nodes a and b as pointers, which they are not. If I changes this to:

```
static bool Cmpr(Node a, Node b){
    return a.dist > b.dist;
}
```

I get no errors at all while compiling.

Comment: Thanks, Slay! You are right! I changed my code alot to check if that solves my problem. and forgot to revert it!

I checked and compiled on my local machine with no error! Only get the error when I tried on CodeFights!
Apparently, it has the problem with static methods in general!!!